# Get a list of keys and values in a nested dictionary oriented by index

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dictionary

I have an Excel file with a structure like this:

```
name age status
anna 35 single
petr 27 married
```

I have converted such a file into a nested dictionary with a structure like this:

```
{'anna': {'age':35}, {'status': 'single'}},
{'petr': {'age':27}, {'status': 'married'}}
```

using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('path/to/file')
df.set_index('name',  inplace=True)
print(df.to_dict(orient='index'))
```

But now when running `list(df.keys())` it returns me a list of all keys in the dictionary ('age', 'status', etc) but not 'name'.

My eventual goal is that it returns me all the keys and values by typing a name.

Is it possible somehow? Or maybe I should use some other way to import a data in order to achieve a goal? Eventually I should anyway come to a dictionary because I will merge it with other dictionaries by a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need parameter `drop=False` to [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for not drop column `Name`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('path/to/file')

df.set_index('name',  inplace=True, drop=False)
print (df)
      name  age   status
name                    
anna  anna   35   single
petr  petr   27  married

d = df.to_dict(orient='index')
print (d)
{'anna': {'age': 35, 'status': 'single', 'name': 'anna'}, 
 'petr': {'age': 27, 'status': 'married', 'name': 'petr'}}

print (list(df.keys()))
['name', 'age', 'status']
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a dataframe from excel, you should do this to obtain the thing you want:

```
resulting_dict = {}

for name, info in df.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: x.to_dict()).iteritems():
    stats = {}
    for key, values in info.items():
        if key != 'name':
            value = list(values.values())[0]
            stats[key] = value
    resulting_dict[name] = stats
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('path/to/file')
df[df['name']=='anna'] #Get all details of anna
df[df['name']=='petr'] #Get all details of petr
```

Comment: thank you, but I should keep it as a dictionary and to turn 'name' into a normal key somehow

Comment: Try : `my_dict = df.set_index('name').transpose().to_dict(orient='list')` and then use `my_dict['anna']` and `my_dict[`petr`]

Comment: it returns me: `UserWarning: DataFrame columns are not unique, some columns will be omitted. "columns will be omitted.", UserWarning)` though the columns are unique